# .NET Core Dynamic Expiration of Identity Cookie Based On Role

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Right now we set the expiration of our Identity Cookie in the StartUp.cs of the project. We have a standard timeout and want to have a dynamic timeout based on the role of the logged in user. I'm looking for direction on how to access the Claims Role to set the Cookie expiration. Is middleware needed?

Basically I am looking for

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options => {

    options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.ExpireTimeSpan = //BasedOnRole);

});
```

this would also work

```
services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>((options) => options.ValidationInterval = //BasedOnRole);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Cookies for `Identity` is `AspNetCore.Identity.Application`, and its `ExpireTimeSpan` is set by [HandleSignInAsync](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/a0d6d3e88f974ac8b66890b34d2c28ebd3f25de0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs#L297).

```
DateTimeOffset issuedUtc;
        if (signInContext.Properties.IssuedUtc.HasValue)
        {
            issuedUtc = signInContext.Properties.IssuedUtc.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            issuedUtc = Clock.UtcNow;
            signInContext.Properties.IssuedUtc = issuedUtc;
        }

        if (!signInContext.Properties.ExpiresUtc.HasValue)
        {
            signInContext.Properties.ExpiresUtc = issuedUtc.Add(Options.ExpireTimeSpan);
        }

        await Events.SigningIn(signInContext);

        if (signInContext.Properties.IsPersistent)
        {
            var expiresUtc = signInContext.Properties.ExpiresUtc ?? issuedUtc.Add(Options.ExpireTimeSpan);
            signInContext.CookieOptions.Expires = expiresUtc.ToUniversalTime();
        }
```

You could implement your own `CookieAuthenticationHandler` by overring `HandleSignInAsync`.

```
    public class CustomCookieAuthenticationHandler : CookieAuthenticationHandler
{
    public CustomCookieAuthenticationHandler(IOptionsMonitor<CookieAuthenticationOptions> options
        , ILoggerFactory logger
        , UrlEncoder encoder
        , ISystemClock clock) : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }

    protected override Task HandleSignInAsync(ClaimsPrincipal user, AuthenticationProperties properties)
    {
        if (user.Identity.Name == "test@outlook.com")
        {
            properties.ExpiresUtc = Clock.UtcNow.AddMinutes(15);
        }
        else
        {
            properties.ExpiresUtc = Clock.UtcNow.AddMinutes(35);
        }
        return base.HandleSignInAsync(user, properties);
    }
}
```

Change the logic to set `properties.ExpiresUtc`.

To replace built-in `CookieAuthenticationHandler`, try to replace it in `Startup`

```
            var descriptor =
            new ServiceDescriptor(
                typeof(CookieAuthenticationHandler),
                typeof(CustomCookieAuthenticationHandler),
                ServiceLifetime.Transient);
        services.Replace(descriptor);
```

Comment: This seems like a solid answer. After implementing this code however HandleSignInAsync is never called in my derived class. The default expiration for my .AspNetCore.Identity.Application cookie is the moment before Epoch time.

Comment: @ScottClark This is my test [project](https://github.com/Edward-Zhou/AspNetCore/tree/b82efe2d4676ebcede8d54463b87102d750fd800/RazorPageIdentity), share how to reproduce your issue with this project.

Comment: Just to verify, so is the ReadCookieTicket method in CookieAuthenticationHandler.cs used at some point during every request to verify the authentication cookie, "AspNetCore.Identity.Application" has not expired? I know most browsers usually delete an expired cookie, but just want to make sure for some reason if the user is still using an expired cookie, if I Identity is already making sure behind the scenes it can't be used. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Hi in startup You can add the cookies

```js
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
    options.Cookie.Name = "YourAppCookieName";
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
    options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
    // ReturnUrlParameter requires 
    //using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
    options.ReturnUrlParameter = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.ReturnUrlParameter;
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});
```